# Multiple select form on rails polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, controller

The association is working fine since I can play with it on IRB. Also I can **edit** existing books to add tags but I **can't** create and assign a tag at the same time ("Tags is invalid" validation error). I suppose it's a form / controller issue, I think I have to .build it but I can't figure it out how.

```
## Tag model (:tags)
belongs_to :genre                                                              
belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true

## Genre model (:genres)
has_many :tags                                                                 
has_many :taggables, through: :tags   

## Serie model (:series)
has_many :tags, as: :taggable, dependent: :destroy                             
has_many :genres, through: :tags 

## Book model (:books)
has_many :tags, as: :taggable, dependent: :destroy                             
has_many :genres, through: :tags
```

Series_Controller

```
before_action :select_genre

[...]

def new                                                                        
  @series = current_user.series.build                                           
end

def edit
end

def create                                                                     
  @serie = current_user.series.build series_params                              
  @serie.save                                                               
    redirect_to admin_series_path         
  end                                                             
end 

[...]
# Useful
def select_genre                                                                
  @genres = Genre.all                                                        
end
```

Form

```
<select name="serie[genre_ids][]" multiple="multiple">
  <% @series.each do |serie| %>                                            
    <option value="<%= serie.id %>"><%= serie.name %></option>
  <% end %>                                                                
</select>
```

---

---

**Edit: Thank you @Fabrizio Bertoglio, it works fine for single options but I couldn't make it work for multiple genres.**

```
# SERIES CONTROLLER
def new
  @series = current_user.series.build                                           
  @series.tags.build                                                            
end

# PARAMS
params.require(:serie).permit ...... tags_attributes: [ :genre_id ]

# GENRE MODEL
** adding 'optional: true' to 'belongs_to :taggable' **
```

Form

```
<select name="serie[tags_attributes][0][genre_id]">
  <% @series.each do |serie| %>                                            
    <option value="<%= serie.id %>"><%= serie.name %></option>
  <% end %>                                                                
</select>
```

As I said before it works fine but if I swap `genre_id` with `genre_ids` it stop working instead allowing the user to select multiple genres and create multiple tags.

```
# CONTROLLER
params.require(:serie).permit ...... tags_attributes: [ { genre_ids: [] } ]    

# FORM
<select name="serie[tags_attributes][0][genre_ids][]" multiple="multiple">
```

Comment: Please also show the method definition of `series_params`

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow this instructions for [building complex forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms).

This way you can create a form that has the input values for creating `@serie`, but also for creating `@serie.tags`.

You need to read that guide, but in synthesis you need to do the following 3 steps:

1. Configure the model and allow `nested_attributes`
2. Build a nested form
3. In the controller, configure your strong params for the nested object
4. Instanciate the variable `@serie` in the controller with your strong_params, so that it will create the associated object